# When touch and pain are caused by heat/cold or pressure how are the nerve cells triggered?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry

I suppose that when your skin is smoothly touched by any cold/heat or pressure we feel that because our AB cells notice this due to a kind of change in the nerve cell. 
But when you touch something hot but not noxious how is that registered different from something what is cold or puts pressure on the skin. How works their mechanisms differently?

A step further is when due to heat/cold or pressure inflammation is started. I read that there are for each stimuly different receptors available. But what is the difference between an inflammation caused by heat/cold and pressure. How can heat create a different cascade of enzymes compare to pressure while both are inflammations and not adding any chemicals of themselves?

Comment: The receptors (and the sensory neurons) for different stimuli are different.